# Can't insert numbers with decimal

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with inserting decimal numbers. The code is a "earning system" that calculate salary. The query insert 2 instead of 2.50.

My code looks like this:

```
$quantity = "1";
$earned = $quantity * '2.5'; //type = double
//.. query update to table etc..
```

Mysql:

```
`earned` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
```

I tried to echo $earned, and it says 2,5 instead of 2.5 would that be the problem??

**Solution:**
I removed my setlocale

Comment: If you echo `$earned` and it shows `2,5` instead of `2.5` then you're doing something else besides simply echoing it

Comment: @MarkBaker I dont have anything to replace the dot with a comma in my code.

Comment: BTW, '2.5' is a string

Comment: A multiplication will return a float; echoing a float will display using a decimal point (.) unless something elsewhere in your code is changing that value. Are you using sprint() or number_fommat() or similar?

Comment: @MarkBaker Just tested in another file, and it turns out that there it echo 2.5, but still double. Can it have something to do with my locale? I set locale to danish in my header..

Comment: locale will not have any affect if you're simply echoing a variable that contains a float value

Comment: I don't use number_format(), but isn't it possible to change it back to dot instead of comma

Comment: Yes, it's possible to change it back.... but you shouldn't need to.... you're doing something else in your code, no matter what you say.... do a var_dump() of the value immediately after your multiplication

Comment: I got it sorted out, it was my locale, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use number type values instead of strings,try this..

```
$quantity = 1;
$earned = $quantity * 2.5;
```

Comment: That didn't help, it's still inserting 2

Comment: please check whether the column "earned" is of correct type DECIMAL(15,2) @MichaelWestergaard no other possibility of data loss

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, since you didn't post your actual mysql query, but most likely the `2.5` value is converted in `2,5` by your locale settings.
The easiest solution is to quote all the values you are putting inside your query, so you won't have any side-effects